# SSIS Package Cancels instantly on Debug

Tags: sql, ssis, etl, flat-file

I have a rather simple SSIS package that I've used many times to import a tab delimited file into a single table in a database.

I attached a new source file to the package and attempted to run the package.

- The package starts
- A cmd prompt appears briefly, then disappears [?!]
- The process then exits, on the Flat File Source component. [??!]
- Output displays as follows:

> SSIS package "C:\Users...\Conversion\LoadHistory.dtsx"
>   starting.
>
> Information: 0x4004300A at Load  Data to Legacy
>   Database - Test, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
>
> Information: 0x4004300A at Load Data to Legacy Database -
>   Test, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
>
> Information:
>   0x40043006 at Load Data to Legacy Database - Test,
>   SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning. Information:
>   0x40043007 at Load Data to Legacy Database - Test,
>   SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
>
> Information: 0x402090DC
>   at Load Data to Legacy Database - Test, Flat File Source
>   [14]: The processing of file
>   "C:\Users...\Conversion\Production\Historicals\Source_2341.txt" has started.
>
> Information: 0x4004300C at Load
>    Data to Legacy Database - Test, SSIS.Pipeline: Execute
>   phase is beginning.
>
> **SSIS package "C:\Users...\Conversion\LoadHistory.dtsx"
>   finished: Canceled.**
>
> **The program '[4380] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has
>   exited with code 0 (0x0).**

The file appears to adhere to the format specs I am expecting. The only concern I can think of is that the file originally was encoded as UCS-2 Little Endian and we are expecting a UTF-8 or ANSI format. I used Notepad++ to re-encode the file as UTF-8 and the file passed the initial meta-data checks as a result, so I have to assume that is resolved.

I am not sure what could be causing the package to automatically cancel.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Can you run other packages out of Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, all of my other packages are working normally. It appears to be only related to this one package.

Comment: Can you run the package using the dtexec command line? C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe /file <filepath> - maybe not 100, whatever version of SSIS you're on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue. It appears the file being used as a source was to blame afterall. The UTF-8 format, while passing the meta-data check, appears to be at fault. I converted the file to ANSI format, as a shot in the dark, and was able to import the file normally without the above anomalies.

I am not sure as to why command prompt was opening however.

Thank you for the responses

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading OS the problem started, changed Visual Studio to ran as Administrator.
That fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue today. It was caused by one of records in the file.